# C++ Multithreaded code executes in the same time as the singlethreaded

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following code (multithreaded version):

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < videos.size(); ++i ) {
      threads.push_back(std::thread([&features, i]() {
           for (size_t j = 0; j < videos.at(i).size(); ++j) {
               features.extract(...);
           }
      });
      threads.back().join();
}
```

The problem is that the singlethreaded version takes approximately 3 mins to execute and the multithreaded once again takes approximately 3 mins to execute. The outer for loops two times so there are two threads. Shouldn't I see some improvement on the execution time? Even some seconds?

Comment: You should not join immediately... As then your working in serial with the overhead of thread creation...

Comment: @Jarod42 When should I join? Maybe right after the outer loop?

Comment: also you have to join the entire vector of threads.

Comment: Downvoters please explain what's wrong with my question so I can be better next time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not join immediately... As then your working in serial with the overhead of thread creation...

Your code should look like:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != videos.size(); ++i ) {
    threads.emplace_back([&features, i]() {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < videos.at(i).size(); ++j) {
            features.extract(...);
        }
    });
}
for (auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Your comment above explains why it should be so, I suggest adding it here as well for a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks, it did worked. surprisingly from 3mins it went down to just 25secs, and yes it gives the same results as the singlethreaded, but how is this even possible? I mean I thought best scenario was to reduce the execution time to half (1.5mins) since there are 2 threads.